# dynamic html from jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-html

I have a JS function that records HTML into the DIV:
 `$("#DivHtml").html('what i want...')`

the HTML also has   `<select>`   with `option` list

the selection has  `EVENT`- `onchange`

This event call to `Jquery` function 
where change the HTML and adds attribute (html in DivHtml)

but after function is occur,

I display the innerHTML of DivHtml and I see that HTML remains the same as I did it at first,

He has not changed from the function in event onchange
(I'm sure he went to a function - I did ALERT)

why?

Comment: it is better to post your code than to explain what you need.. so please post your related code.. before you start getting downvotes and mostly this question getting closed..

Comment: Could you maybe be more clear in your question? I'm having trouble understanding what it is exactly that you need.

Comment: Or better post a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: How are you binding the change event? I'm guessing not by using `$(document).on('change', '#DivHtml select', function(e){});`

Comment: The `onchange` event **is** or **is not** being triggered when you pass the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need either to [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the new html or use `.on` (removing the inline onchange) like:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectID', function(){...});
```

**PS:** I think you mean `<select>` and not `<selection>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that the event you attached the `select` is lost when you update the content of the div via `html()`? If that is the case, the reason is because the element which the event was bound to has been removed from the DOM and a new one has been added in it's place.

The easiest solution is to use a delegated event handler, bound to the container like this:

```
// your HTML updating logic
$("#DivHtml").html('what i want...')

// select change handler
$('#DivHtml').on('change', 'select', function() {
   alert('select value was changed');
});
```